# Select several years pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to select several years from a dataframe in monthly resolution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4 as nc

#-- open net-cdf and read in variables
data = nc.Dataset('test.nc')

time = nc.num2date(data.variables['Time'][:],
                   data.variables['Time'].units)

df = pd.DataFrame(data.variables['mgpp'][:,0,0], columns=['mgpp'])

df['dates'] = time
df = df.set_index('dates')
print(df.head())
```

This is what the head looks like:

```
                mgpp
dates               
1901-01-01  0.040735
1901-02-01  0.041172
1901-03-01  0.053889
1901-04-01  0.066906
```

Now I managed to extract one year:

```
df_cp = df[df.index.year == 2001]
```

but how would I extract several years, say 1997, 2001 and 2007 and have them stored in the same dataframe? Is there a one/ two line solution? My only idea for now is to iterate and then merge the dataframes but maybe there is a better solution!

Comment: `df[df.index.year.isin([1997, 2001, 2007])]`

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for